# Error in production with premailer-rails:the asset "mailer.css" is not present in the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, actionmailer, premailer

I'm using premailer-rails to inline-style emails in a 5.1.6 Rails app.

Everything is working fine in development, but I get this error in production (heroku)

`The asset "mailer.css" is not present in the asset pipeline`

I have defined a file `assets\stylesheets\mailer.css`

In the mailer layout I have: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag :mailer %>`

I have also added this to `assets.rb`: `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( mailer.css )`

How can I fix it?

Comment: How do you precompile your assets at the moment ?

Comment: what do you mean? I don't do anything special

Comment: Well if your stylesheets are located in app/assets/stylesheets they need to be compiled into the public folder. Otherwise they will be missing : https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html If you deploy through Heroku, Heroku will take care of that for you. But you can also precompile locally which I find better. To fix this type `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` in console and check your public folder. You will see all your assets put there. Then try to deploy.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, now I understand what you meant. And it worked to precimpile locally! (although i'm in heroku and as you said it should take care of it). Please make an answer and I will accept it as correct :)

Comment: No worries, don't need to make it an answer :) Heroku can precompile but it warns against it : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#compile-set-to-true-in-production In your production environnement file, just write `config.assets.compile = false` and precompile locally. You can also set it to true but I have noticed that my Heroku slug was much bigger and some weird things sometimes happen.

Comment: Also you can decide what minimizers you want. Mine are : `config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier` `config.assets.css_compressor = :sass` But for example I think `uglifier` does not accept Javascript ES6; In case you have JS file with ES6 you may encounter some errors. And then you can remove the JS file with ES6 from your assets.rb file in order for it not to be precompiled. Assets.rb file just tells Rails which files you want to belong to the precompile.

Comment: @Maxence You're steering Ernesto the wrong way on a couple of important points here. First, your claim is backwards on what Heroku recommends for asset compilation; Heroku does *not* recommend against against allowing it to do the precompiling, it actually recommends that you do the opposite. The document you linked specifically says "we recommend either precompiling all of your assets on deploy (which is the default)  or **if that is not possible** compiling assets locally."

Comment: @Maxence Secondly, you're mistaken about what `config.assets.compile` does. It has nothing to do with `rake assets:precompile`. It's completely fine to allow Heroku to run `rake assets:precompile` for you, and that isn't controlled by `config.assets.compile`. Heroku (and everybody else) recommends turning off `config.assets.compile` in production (which is off by default anyways) because that setting controls whether assets can be *dynamically* compiled, meaning if you don't precompile your assets, your server will fall back to dynamical compilation, which is slow.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't want to mislead anyone. I try to give advice both on my thin experience and documentation, that I don't exclude I can sometimes misinterpret. Thanks for claryfing about the precompiling of assets. (for Ernesto and me)